# Cannot upload a image file in the EPiServersite

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I have created a EPIServer CMS site using visual studio. I am able to access the site using edit mode. I want to add some image on that site. But when I am trying to upload a image using the upload option it is showing failed message.Why it is happening do you have any idea. But when I have uploaded the images from the demp 'Aloy Site' given by EPIServer team it is uploaded successfully.
Please tell the probable cause of this.

Thanks and regards
Utpal Maity

Comment: Check that your VPP folders are configured correctly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also got the fail to upload images. Firstly I thought it was a config-setting or a permission problem. But it turned out that I needed a "media descriptor".

You can read about it [here](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-CMS/75/Content/Assets-and-media/Media-types-and-templates/). This applies for EPiServer CMS 7.x

C# example:

```
[ContentType]
[MediaDescriptor(ExtensionString = "jpg,jpeg,jpe,gif,bmp,png")]
public class ImageFile : ImageData
{
    public virtual string AlternativeText { get; set; }
}
```